# Customize [AllowHtml] to allow specific html tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to customize the AllowHtml attribute to allow   tag to be passed through to the action of an controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I am afraid that this is not possible. You could implement this *filtering* afterwards.

Comment: So the best way would be to check whether the property contains html data when its posted to the controller? Is there an easier way to check for html tags in a string instead of using an loop?

Comment: Sure, you could use an HTML parser such as HTML Agility Pack. I really hope you are not going to parse HTML manually by using loops and regular expressions.

Comment: Haha! i was going to use regular expressions. Now will use HTML Agility Pack. Thanks for the help mate really appreciate it. BTW Congratz on 400k :).

Comment: You were going to use regular expressions? Really? Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: The post talks about parsing html, i was just gonna validate the input to check whether it contains any html tags. Surely this would be possible with regex...

Comment: Hey Darin, similar question, is there a way to overright the @html.raw() helper to render specific html tags?

Comment: No, there isn't. But you could write your own custom helper.